# How to count webform radio button submissions

Tags: webforms

What would be the best way to count all submissions (True & False) of a radio button type in a web form?

There are about 100 radio buttons in each survey form so need to get a total number of True values

Answer (score 0):

If you want do the number count after submit is done

1. Login as Admin
2. open your webfrom
3. Click Result
4. From webfrom menu click Analysis

It will give you the most complete Analysis of your form.

Comment: Thanks...

What I really need is access to the raw values so I can include them in a custom template. Are they available in the $variable ? or which table do the YES / NO values stored in order to query and collate?

Comment: @is_numeric in that case you can use a custom php code and you can use dev module [https://www.drupal.org/project/devel]to find out about location of the yes/no

Answer (score 0):

This pulls all submissions and results

SELECT 
            `webform_submitted_data`.`sid`,
            `webform_submitted_data`.`data`,
            `webform_component`.`type`,
            `webform_component`.`form_key`,
            `webform_component`.`name`
           FROM
            `webform_submitted_data`
          INNER JOIN 
            `webform_component` ON (`webform_submitted_data`.`cid` = `webform_component`.`cid`)
          WHERE
            `webform_submitted_data`.`sid` = :sid AND 
            `webform_component`.`type` = 'select'
          GROUP BY
            webform_component.form_key